# Tunelling link data through PHP?

Tags: php, tunnel

I want to be able to go to `mydoma.in/tunnel.php?file=http://otherdoma.in/music.mp3`, and then get the data of `http://otherdoma.in/music.mp3` streamed to the client.

I tried doing this via `Header();`, but it redirects instead of "tunelling" the data.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use cURL for streaming:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET["file"];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 256);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Would that not download the whole file first? I want to to this while keeping as little on the hard disk as possible.

Comment: I think each 256 bytes, it flushes to the stdout (webbrowser in this case). It shouldn't use more than CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE bytes of memory.

Comment: Ah, i'll try this out. This sounds like a fine solution :)

Comment: well... take care as this is highly INSECURE. You should ensure that "file" variable is web site. mydoma.in/tunnel.php?file=file:///etc/passwd will expose the proxy passwd file

Comment: I know, i'll add some protocol white-listing or something. I found a problem though, this does not appear to work with `https` requests, which i need for this project. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have your PHP script pull the remote content:

```
$data = file_get_contents($remote_url);
```

And then just spit it out:

```
echo $data;
```

Or simply:

```
echo file_get_contents($remote_url);
```

You might have to add some headers to indicate the content type.

Alternatively, you could configure a proxy with something like [`nginx`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) -- this will allow you to rewrite particular URLs to a remote site and then serve them as local, no coding required.

Comment: Using file_get_contents would require downloading the whole file first right? I'm looking for something that can "stream" it.

The nginx thing looks interesting - i use nginx, and i am familiar with it, but i only know the basic config files. I assume i'll have to use rewrite and these proxy rules, how would i go about that?

Comment: Yes file_get_contents will download the whole file first. The nginx link provided gives examples. I've just highlighted it in case you didn't notice it was a link.

Comment: I understand what you mean, i just don't know how to configure nginx to proxy a url specified in the url (I.E. `domain.com/tunnel/{URL}` would proxy `{URL}`).

Answer (score 0):

If they are small, you might be able to use file_get_contents(). Otherwise, you should probably use cURL. You would want to cURL the URL from the get variable "file". Then save it to a local temporary location with PHP. Then, use header() to direct yourself to the local file. Deleting the temporary file is the only issue, as there isn't really a way to determine when you have finished downloading it or not. So you might be able to sleep or delay the file removal, but you might find it's a better option to use a cron job to clean up all of the temporary files later.